# API automation - conditional test

Tags: javascript, api, conditional-statements, postman

before you will read it, I'm a total noob, sorry for that.

I have some endpoint that will return different statuses depending on how many times this endpoint is called. Either it will return status 200 or 409 with some extra information. For the latter case, it will return something like that:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ABC",
        "message": "ABC",
        "target": null,
        "innerError": null,
        "details": null
    }
}
```

and I would like the test to pass if either the status will be equal to 200 or if it will be 409 with "message": "ABC".

I've been trying it in different ways, but I'm stuck with it. My latest attempt would look like this:

```
pm.test("Status is 200 or ABC", function () {
    if(pm.response.code !== 200)
    {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var expectedObject = {
    "message": "ABC"

    }
    }
    else
    {
        (pm.response.to.have.status(200))
        console.log("Success")
    }
});
```

and it would pass this test even when the status is not 200 and if the body doesn't contain the "message": "ABC".

Any ideas on how I could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some type of check for the test to pass/fail. The condition should be something like this:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
// expecting that jsonData.message will be equal to "ABC"
pm.expect(jsonData.message).to.eql("ABC")
```

In case of doubt, [check the docs](https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html)